# Jquery json request and Kohana

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, kohana

I am trying to learn a little bit of jquery and more about the kohana framework.  Ok so I wrote a simple test script to grab some entries from a database.  The php works as in it returns the row in a json format, but I guess my jquery isn't working.

The json is suppose to return multiple rows so I want it to add all of those into the #chats div.
Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('json/get_chat_entries/1',
    function(data) {
      $('#chats').append('<li>' + data.text + '</li>');
    }
  });
});
```

The get entries code is suppose to grab all the entries in the database matching the chat_id.  Write now it seems to be only returning the first entry.
here is my get entries code:

```
function get_entries() {
  $entries = $result = DB::select() - > from('chat_entries') - > where('chat_id', '=', $this - > chat_id) - > execute() - > current();
  return $entries;
}
```

And this is the controller code:

```
public function action_get_chat_entries(){
  $chat_id = $this->request->param('id');
  $chat = new Model_Chat($chat_id);
  echo json_encode($chat->get_entries());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `->current()` from your `get_entries()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up a bit:

Model:

```
public function get_entries()
{
    if (!$this->_loaded)
        return array();

    return DB::select()
        ->from('chat_entries')
        ->where('chat_id', '=', $this->chat_id)
        ->execute($this->_db);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function action_get_chat_entries()
{
    $id = $this->request->param('id', FALSE);
    $chat = new Model_Chat($id);

    $this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $this->request->response = json_encode($chat->get_entries());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = DB::select(...)->from(...)->where(...)->execute();
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($results));
```